# Will my US overstay affect my chances of getting a UK Work Visa

Tags: usa, united-kingdom, working-visas, immigration, overstay

I overstayed my student visa in the US by a couple of years. Now I have a job offer in the UK and will be applying for a Tier 2 work visa. Will my US overstay affect my chances of getting the UK visa?

Answer (score 5):

It might.

According to the [Treaty between US and UK on Immigration Information Sharing](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/282580/8790.pdf):

> “Information” means data on Nationals of a Third Country seeking authorization to transit through, travel to, work in, live in, or take citizenship of, the United Kingdom (UK) or the United States (U.S.), and other immigration and nationality-related data about Nationals of a Third Country, including data from admissibility, immigration or nationality compliance actions and/or decisions rendered in accordance with the immigration and nationality laws of the respective Parties. Information may consist of personal data, statistical data, or both.  The particular types of Information to be shared, and categories of Nationals of a Third Country about whom such Information is to pertain, shall be described in relevant implementing arrangements developed by the Parties pursuant to Article 4.

I was not able to find the exact details on which information is shared and in which cases but it is possible that your overstay may come up during your vetting process by UK immigration authorities.